# Copying a range of cells from one worksheet to another

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to code that would allow me to filter a very larget set of data (~10,000 rows) and then  copy and paste the filtered data onto Another worksheet.

Ultimately, I am trying to filter based on the first left digits of the phone number, and then to filter again with 5 digits, and so on and on until I have a single row. And also to display each pasted filtered results on a list box.

```
Sub CopyPaste()

    Dim Data As Worksheet
    Dim Filtered As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long
    Dim row As Long
    Dim col As Integer
    col = 3
    Dim Copy As Range
    Dim Paste As Range

    Set Data = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set Filtered = Sheets("Sheet2")

    For i = 2 To Sheet1.Range("A:A").End(xlUp).row

        If Left(Sheet1.Cells(i, 1), 4) = Me.ComboBox1.Value Then
            With Data
                Set Copy = .Range(.Cells(i, 1), .Cells(i, 3))
            End With 
            With Filtered
                Set Paste = .Range(.Cells(i, 1), .Cells(i, 3))
            End With
            Copy.Copy Destination:=Paste
        End If
    Next i 
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    Dim row As Integer
    Dim col As Integer
    Dim newRow As Integer 
        
    ' For ####
    If Len(Me.ComboBox1) = 4 Then
        Sheet1.Range("A2").AutoFilter _
          Field:=1, _
          Criteria1:=">" & ComboBox1.Value * 10 ^ 6, _
          Operator:=xlAnd, _
          Criteria2:="<" & ComboBox1.Value * 10 ^ 6 + 999999
     
        Call CopyPaste
    End If 
End Sub
```

From the above code, CopyPaste() does not seem to work at all. I am able to filter based on the first 4 digits of the phone number.

I've been stuck here for about a week. Any help or tutorial link would be very much appreciated.

Comment: what's the error? Can you add file screen shot ?

Comment: I am confused by your comment `' For ### - #` - What data is in your combo box? And which ones are in column A of Sheet1? In addition, filters are absolutely unnecessary for doing this work (IMHO).

Comment: It is good practice to not name your variables with proper commands, i.e. Copy, Paste.  This will cause problems.  Also, “does not work” isn’t as helpful as letting people know what error you are receiving.

Comment: Please, look carefully at your Sheet2 - perhaps you simply do not see the copying result, because it is lower, much lower than the first lines of the sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is longer than the one you showed. But it seems to work and does as intended (I hope so)

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    If Len(Me.ComboBox1) = 4 Then Call CopyPaste(Me.ComboBox1.Text)
End Sub

Sub CopyPaste(ByVal sSearch As String)
Dim wsData As Worksheet, wsFiltered As Worksheet ' Source and target worksheets
Dim rSearch As Range    ' Part of sheet for search subroutine
Dim rToCopy As Range    ' All cells with phone numbers by mask
Dim rCopy As Range, rPaste As Range ' Single cells - source and target
Rem Several decorating additives
Dim totalCells As Long, currentCell As Long
Dim prevPercent As Integer, currPercent As Integer

    Set wsData = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set rSearch = Application.Intersect(wsData.Columns(1), wsData.UsedRange)
    Application.StatusBar = "Searching..."
    Set rToCopy = FindPhone(rSearch, sSearch & "??????") ' It is search by mask ####??????
    Application.StatusBar = False
    If rToCopy Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' Not found
    
    totalCells = rToCopy.Cells.Count ' For status bar

    Set wsFiltered = Sheets("Sheet2")
    Set rSearch = wsFiltered.Columns(1) ' No need doubles, so will validate each before paste

    Set rPaste = wsFiltered.Cells(wsFiltered.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp) ' Last non-empty cell
    currentCell = 0: prevPercent = -1 ' decorating
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each rCopy In rToCopy
Rem again decorating
        currentCell = currentCell + 1
        currPercent = 100 * currentCell / totalCells
        If prevPercent < currPercent Then
            prevPercent = currPercent
            Application.StatusBar = "Copy " & currentCell & " from " & totalCells & " (" & currPercent & "%)"
            DoEvents
        End If
Rem Is it unique phone number?
        If FindPhone(rSearch, rCopy.Text) Is Nothing Then
            Set rPaste = rPaste.Offset(1, 0) ' Shift down target cell
            rCopy.Resize(1, 3).Copy Destination:=rPaste ' Copy 3 cells
        End If
    Next rCopy
    Application.StatusBar = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Function FindPhone(SearchRange As Range, FindWhat As Variant) As Range
Dim FoundCell As Range
Dim FirstFound As Range
Dim LastCell As Range
Dim ResultRange As Range
Dim Area As Range
Dim MaxRow As Long, MaxCol As Long
    For Each Area In SearchRange.Areas
        With Area
            If .Cells(.Cells.Count).row > MaxRow Then
                MaxRow = .Cells(.Cells.Count).row
            End If
            If .Cells(.Cells.Count).Column > MaxCol Then
                MaxCol = .Cells(.Cells.Count).Column
            End If
        End With
    Next Area
    Set LastCell = SearchRange.Worksheet.Cells(MaxRow, MaxCol)
    
    Set FoundCell = SearchRange.Find(what:=FindWhat, _
            after:=LastCell, _
            LookIn:=xlValues, _
            LookAt:=xlWhole, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
            MatchCase:=False)
    
    If Not FoundCell Is Nothing Then
        Set FirstFound = FoundCell
        Do Until False ' Loop forever. We'll "Exit Do" when necessary.
            If ResultRange Is Nothing Then
                Set ResultRange = FoundCell
            Else
                Set ResultRange = Application.Union(ResultRange, FoundCell)
            End If
            Set FoundCell = SearchRange.FindNext(after:=FoundCell)
            If (FoundCell Is Nothing) Then
                Exit Do
            End If
            If (FoundCell.Address = FirstFound.Address) Then
                Exit Do
            End If
        Loop
    End If
    Set FindPhone = ResultRange
End Function
```